# WebDriver + Groovy: how to choose an option in drop down list?

Tags: drop-down-menu, groovy, webdriver

Could you please help me withi choosing a value in drop down list? There pieces of code don't work:

1) Here, I managed to click on drop-down list and mark the required option, but was unable to choose (click) it:

```
Field = driver.findElement(By.id("DriverID"))
Field.click()
Thread.sleep(5000)
Field.sendKeys("Alan")
Thread.sleep(5000)
Field.sendKeys(Keys.Enter)
```

2) Here, nothing happened:

```
Field = driver.findElement(By.id("DriverID"))
Field.deselectAll()
Field.SelectByValue("Alan")
```

3) Here, nothing happened:

```
Field = driver.findElement(By.id("DriverID"))   
Field.findElements(By.tagName("option")).find{ it.text == "Alan"}.setSelected()
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Racoon

Comment: Can you post the html source of the select object?

Comment: That's commercial. Nothing special are there: "select" tag with "option" tags inside.

Comment: And one of the options is `<option value="Alan">Alan</option>` yeah?  #justchecking ;-)

Comment: Almost. ...<option value="19">Alan</option><option value="20">Dave</option>...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Field.selectByValue("19")` then or does `Field.selectByVisibleText( 'Alan' )` work?

Comment: To hard-code 19 is not good for me. I tried selectByVisibleText but go t the following: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.selectByVisibleText() is
applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Alan]

Comment: Hmmm...can you try: `new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DriverID"))).selectByVisibleText( 'Alan' )`  Sorry about the guesswork, I don;t have webdriver setup on my machine :-(

Comment: And I have this: import org.openqa.selenium.*
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select

Comment: Tim, it works! Thanks! I wish I could turn up your karma!

Comment: Posted it as an answer :-)  Glad we got it working, and sorry for the scatter-gun approach ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I wish I asked earlier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to construct a `Select` object from the web element, then call `selectByVisibleText` on it:

```
def element = driver.findElement( By.id( "DriverID" ) )
def select  = new Select( element )
select.selectByVisibleText( 'Alan' )
```